# Template version of virtual function calls from vector of objects

Tags: c++, templates, vector, polymorphism

Is it possible to achieve something similar to the pseudo-code below via templates? If so what's the correct way to get proper compile-time polymorphism here? Thanks!

```
class Base {virtual void DoSomething();};
class Derived:public Base{void DoSomething();};
class Derived1:public Base{void DoSomething();};
class Derived2... etc.

std::vector<Base*> bases;
bases.push_back(new Derived());
bases.push_back(new Derived1());
etc...

bases[i]->DoSomething();
```

*EDIT*

since the above caused some confusion, i thought i should add an example of a proposed starting solution i just found that was given for a question similar to my own. this was pulled from an old australian linux c++ board from 2001  http://lists.linux.org.au/archives/tuxcpprogramming/2001-August/000135.html:

```
squareTy square;
twiceTy twice;
thriceTy thrice;

functionBaseTy* fns[] = { &square, &twice, &thrice };

template <class T, int N>
inline
void my_algorithm(T* functions[N])
{
 // This deduces T and the array size N
  my_real_algorithm(functions, N);
} 

template <class T> // not inline
void my_real_algorithm(T* functions, int n)
{
  // Loop here ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If your container (vector) tracks a collection of base class instance pointers, you need to pay the standard vtable pointer/indirection per instance (or custom equivalent which is probably not worth the effort).

The possibility of statically eliminating vtable/function pointer overhead only presents itself when you know the concrete (derived) type at compile time.

Comment: ok, thanks. is there a way of doing something similar, perhaps without using a runtime vector (since it requires base class pointers)? perhaps, having the vector embedded in the template?

Comment: even if you could generate `n` vectors tracking `n` concrete types at compile time, if your intention is to somehow aggregate these vectors into a "master" `Base*` tracking vector, then iterating over this master-base vector polymorphically will still incur similar costs. The only way you can avoid these costs altogether is to run over each vector<ConcreteType> independently. As an aside, have you profiled? and is this really a bottleneck for you?

Comment: my last comment had no specific intention other than wondering if it's possible to skip a v-table lookup for calling a sub-class with just an integer at your disposal (keying to a class) "somehow" via templates, not necessarily with vectors. as to your aside, the question was posed to increase my knowledge of c++, namely template meta-programming, which takes precedence over any "premature optimization" you're implying i'm partaking in.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that is possible, How about below code?

```
std::vector<Base*> bases;
bases.push_back(new Derived());
bases.push_back(new Derived1());

//...

bases[i]->DoSomething();
```

Comment: thanks, i was looking for converting all of the above into a template version of that polymorphism. i think my incorrect pseudo-code threw you off. sorry about that.

Comment: will update question with that code to avoid any more confusion.